# How to create grid-view dynamically with crud operations or how create multiple gridviews dynamically with Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

the c# code for multiple gridview(working code). this will create multiple gridviews but delete and edit are not working.

```
     GridView gv = new GridView();
               // gv.DeleteMethod("DeleteData");
                gv.ID = "_gridview" + categoryId;
                gv.AutoGenerateEditButton = true;
                gv.AutoGenerateDeleteButton = true;
                gv.DataSource = objSpearController.GetSpearSiteDetails(siteID, categoryId);
                gv.DataBind();
                GridPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(gv);
                GridPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
                gv.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(resourceSet.GetString(categoryId.ToString()));
                gv.RowDeleting += new GridViewDeleteEventHandler(gv_RowDeleting);
```

Event handlers for the above code. sorry for the mistakes.I am a Beginner.

```
       public void gv_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView gv = (GridView)sender;
        try
        {
            int SiteId = int.Parse(ddlSiteName.SelectedValue);
            int result = objSpearController.deleteSbdData(SiteId);
            LoadSpearSiteNames();
            ddlCategory.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblError.Text = ex + "error";
        }
    }
```

Comment: where are the event handlers?

Comment: @Asif.Ali i have edited the code. if you would like to see.